# Rails dynamic data progress bar using bootrap progress bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

Hi can anyone help with trying to get a bootrap 5 progress bar to show dynamic data from my meetings table ? Rails 6.0.4 Ruby 2.7.0p0

I have a table `rails g Scaffold meetings name:string start_date:datetime end_date:datetime duration:integer`

Duration is a calculated field in my meetings.rb which is saved to my db

```
def set_duration
      self.duration = (end_date - start_date).to_i
    end
```

in my meeting.index.erb i have

```
<% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>

<td><%= meeting.start_date %></td>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"  style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><%= Time.at(meeting.duration).utc.strftime("%H hours and %M minutes ")  %></div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

im trying to show it so i can see the total duration hours out of a total of 8 hours or 28800 seconds but the bar will not show bootrab is working as i can generate progress bar without dynamic data. Can anyone point me in right direction?
[image]

[image]

screenshot after code update progress bar still wont appear dynamically
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Read the document and example well](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/progress/).

`style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25"` represent progress. So you need to calculate how % from meeting duration against 24 hours.

So your `Meeting` model can have the following method returning %

```
def duration_percent
  duration / 24.hours.to_f * 100
end
```

and modify your ERB template to render percentage

<% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"  style="width: <%= meeting.duration_percent %>%;" aria-valuenow="<%= meeting.duration_percent %>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><%= Time.at(meeting.duration).utc.strftime("%H hours and %M minutes ")  %></div</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Amit Patel thank you for your help for some reason the progress bar stil doesnt show for me i have added a screenshot of the output i get after adding your code. Not sure why it wont show dynamically but will show static progress bar fine ?